# How can show a new detail cell when i click on cell in TableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm making an app about AutoChess. The TableView, I show all heroes. I want to click on the hero cell, then it can show a new cell, this cell has some stats about that hero. this is my code and image that i want it look like. Thanks for your help

ViewController

```
extension HeroesViewController : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return tableHero.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tableHero[section].count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let tableSection = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HeroViewCell", for: indexPath) as! HeroViewCell
    let heroObj = tableHero[indexPath.section]
    tableSection.configCell(obj : heroObj, indexPath : indexPath)
    return tableSection
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.backgroundColor = .clear
}
```

}
HeroViewCell

```
class HeroViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var imgAvatar: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var lblName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lblBuff: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var imgAbility: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var lblCost: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

func configCell(obj : [Hero], indexPath : IndexPath){
    self.imgAvatar.image = UIImage(named: obj[indexPath.row].avatar!)
    self.lblName.text = obj[indexPath.row].nameHero
    self.lblBuff.text = obj[indexPath.row].races?.joined(separator: " \n ")
    if let imgAblityName = obj[indexPath.row].ability?.imageAbility{
        self.imgAbility.image = UIImage(named: imgAblityName)
    }

    self.lblCost.text = obj[indexPath.row].cost
}
```

}

[This is i want my table look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9HUV.jpg)

Comment: So what's the issue that you have trouble with?  And what are 'Audochess' and 'the hero cell'?

Comment: i have an image there.I cannot make a new cell when I press the old cell. The new cell will show details about old cell

Comment: woah there buckaroo... that statement was kinda confusing..

Answer (score 3):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let Storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "nameOfStoryboard", bundle: nil)

        let DvC = Storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:      "UIViewControllerIdentifer") as! className


         navigationController?.pushViewController(DvC, animated: true)

    }
```

basically something like that, just when you call the global variables from the class you can reference it like `DvC.varableName = array[indexPath.row].nameOfStoredVarible` or if you don't have a sorted variable you can do `DvC.varableName = array[indexPath.row]` hope this helps!!

Comment: Don't forget that the "nameOfStoryboard" must be configured in Identity Inspector Panel on the StoryBoard ID attribute

Comment: ah yes, this is very true. Forgot to mention that when I wrote this response.

Answer (score 0):

From `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` -function, update the object for the selected index in `tableHero` -array, by setting a selected flag for example. Then call `reloadRows(at indexPaths: [IndexPath], 
           with animation: UITableView.RowAnimation)` on the table-view to reload the cell.

You could also insert a new cell below the current `IndexPath`. In `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` -function, create a new object and add it to the `tableHero` -array and insert it below the selected cell by calling: `insertRows(at indexPaths: [IndexPath], with animation: UITableView.RowAnimation)`.

Comment: Can show a new cell? because i edit cell on xib file